# why doesn't ODBC support french accented words when inserting to sql server?

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I am working with php to insert a line in sql server with odbc but I have this problem with french accents ( é , â , ô , î , è ,...), when I insert inside sql server it works and also php reads it well, but when inserting using odbc it is read as a special character

**Example:**

```
$sujet = 'BEM relevé bancaire';

$sql ="INSERT into matrice values('$groupe','$sujet','$nom','$ref','$ref','$next')";

odbc_exec($connection, $sql);
```

**Output:**

> > ID:           542     
> >     groupe:         Groupe_name
> >     CI:             BEM relevÃ© bancaire `//THE PROBLEM`
> >  
> >     Nom:            Name
> >     affectationRef: 1
> >     restAffect:     1
> >     nextAffect:     0

**`How can I make it reads the french accents ?`**

**The possible duplicate doesn't answer my question unfortunately**

Comment: What is the data type of `CI` column?

Comment: You're directly putting your data into the query. Not only is that unsafe, it could create the problem you're trying to fix. Consider [using ODBC prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756369/odbc-prepared-statements-in-php)

Comment: @Zhorov varchar

Comment: @Machavity I edited the code to prepared statements but that didn't fix my problem.

Comment: Post the schema of your table, as well as the collation. Also, have you ensured everything is in UTF8? [That's another common problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: @Machavity it's sql server there's no UTF8. The database collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI.

Comment: Is your PHP script written in UTF8? Does your website serve up UTF8 pages?

Comment: @Machavity yes it does. my PHP reads special characters the problem is when inserting to sql server, the special characters aren't read. And it's not problem of sql server I think it is from odbc, cause I insert in sql server and they are read well, but from odbc they aren't.

Comment: Have you tried [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) by any chance then?

Comment: I'm familiar with PDO but the client I'm working with insists on odbc.

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see the schema of the table to provide a definite answer.   SQL Server data types of char and varchar do not support double-byte characters sets.  Ensure that your table column, that you wish to insert to, has nchar or nvarchar as the data type.

You can test this with a simple table, with multiple columns.  Inserting the same value into column A and column B, will return different results.

```
Create table test (A varchar(20), B nvarchar(20))
Insert into test (A,B) values ('â',N'â')
```

If this does not solve the issue, then I think the client code page differs from that of the sql server code page.   You can read more about this here: [You cannot correctly translate character data from a client to a server by using the SQL Server ODBC driver if the client code page differs from the server code page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/234748/you-cannot-correctly-translate-character-data-from-a-client-to-a-serve)